# How to enforce Restrict DeleteBehavior for migration build using ef?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

I have a `PatientRegistry` table that is related to has three related tables with a `one-to-many` relationship `Country`, `State` and `City`. During migration, the default `DeleteBehavior` is set to `Cascade` which gives me an error during `database Update`. if I change it to `Restrict` I can `seed` properly. I am trying to enforce the `Restrict`behavior during build but I keep getting this error during seeding,

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The association
>   between entity types 'City' and 'PatientRegistry' has been severed but
>   the foreign key for this relationship cannot be set to null. If the
>   dependent entity should be deleted, then setup the relationship to use
>   cascade deletes.

**How can I prevent the cascade delete behavior during build?**

I am posting the relative code,

```
[Table("PatientsRegistry")]
    public class PatientRegistry
    {   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Record Id")]
        public long RecordId { get; set; }
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = "Patient File Number")]
        public long PatientFileId { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public State State { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; }
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PartnerRegistry> Partners { get; set; }
        public PatientRegistry()
        {
            Partners = new Collection<PartnerRegistry>();
        }

    }
```

and in my `OnModelCreating`

```
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Country)
                .WithOne()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(c => c.State)
                .WithOne()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(c => c.City)
                .WithOne()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

and I seed as follow,

```
  if (!context.PatientsRegistry.Any())
                    {

                        context.PatientsRegistry.AddRange(
                             new PatientRegistry
                             {
                                 PatientFileId = 1111,
                                 CountryId = context.Countries.Where(g => g.Name == "Jordan").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 StateId = context.States.Where(g => g.Name == "Amman").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                                 CityId = context.Cities.Where(g => g.Name == "Abu Nusair").SingleOrDefault().Id,
                             }

                        );
                        context.SaveChanges();


                    }
```

Comment: Why `WithOne()` ?

Comment: @IvanStoev, you are absolutely right, I totally got it the other way around,,,, should be `WithMany()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally missed it, should be `WithMany()`

```
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Country)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(c => c.State)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(c => c.City)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```